# Объединить значения при сохранении

Tags: python, json, bs4

Сохраняет в колонку и каждое значение представляется отдельным списком.
Можно ли объединить их в один? допустим под тегом "kill" (при сохранении)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

def kills(x):

    headers = {"User-Agent":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}    

    url = f"https://zkillboard.com/character/{x}/kill"   

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    data = soup.find("div", class_="content")
    kills = data.find_all("tr", class_='killListRow winwin')
   
    for i in kills:        
        # name_c = i.find("td", class_='victim').text.replace("\n"," ") 
        name_c = i.find("td", class_='victim').text
        m = re.findall('\(([^)]+)', name_c)
        
        print(m)      

        with open('my.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump(m, file, indent=4 ,ensure_ascii=False)


kills("rensu")
```

Comment: Загружаете данные из json в список, добавляете туда нужную информацию, сохраняете в тот же файл с перезаписью.